# evaluating limit of infinite iterations of an exponential function.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

**If $f\left(x\right)=\left(x\right)^{\left(x\right)}$, then find- $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(\frac{\left(f\left(f\left(f\left(f\left(........n....f\left(x\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)}{(f(f(f(f(....n..f(f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right))))))^x}\right) $ for $|x|<1$**
How can we apply the l's hopital rule over here?
It is clear that it is a $0/(0^0)$ form. I think the numerator tends faster to 0 than denominator. hence I believe answer is 0, but i have no proof of the fact, nor is it a proper method.
I tried to plot the graph on desmos, and got the following result for the iterations of the function part.-[image: like this]
How can we evaluate it further?
Please help me to reach the answer.
thanks in advanced.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the description of the tag `proof-writing`: For questions about the formulation of a proof. This tag should not be the only tag for a question and **should not be used to ask for a proof of a statement**.

Comment: thanks i will remember that

Comment: And please refrain from adding other irrelevant tags. (How come a purely combinatoric problem is in the field of elementary set theory?)

Comment: sorry about that, actually a careless error